# How to conditionally copy an observation in one column to a new observation in another?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a setting where I try to merge information on families. I have 2 datasets. 1 includes only the oldest member of the family I have information on 'greatestparent'. The other includes all people, including also these greatestparents.

df:

```
greatestparent    person           child
 ID123            ID123            ID345
 ID123            ID123            ID346
```

dfmerge:

```
person  child      
 ID123    ID345      
 ID123    ID346      
 ID345    ID456      
 ID346    n.a.       
 ID456    n.a.
```

The way it works is as follows: I have information on the greatestparent who is uniquely identified with a number. I know that this greatestparent  had children and those children possibly had children as well. To get information for each level of the family I do the following:

```
df=pd.merge(df, dfmerge, left_on=['child'], right_on=['person'], suffixes=(count,count+1),copy=True, how='left')
```

This gives me a parent with all of his/her children. Too conserve memory I then turn the data from a wide to a long format. The level variable keeps track of how many generations after the great-great-grandparent we are.

```
df=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['greatestparent'], value_vars=['person'+str(count), 'person'+str(count+1)],var_name='level', value_name='person')
```

I then merge the information on children back in. This allows me to pick up the next generation.

```
df=pd.merge(df, dfmerge, left_on=['person'], right_on=['person'],copy=True, how='left')
```

I loop this process until we reach the current generation.

The problem is that at any point in this history a family might 'die out'. Moreover, sometimes a child is registered as a person's child, but is not registered as a person him/her self. I want to make sure that this last generation ends up in my list of persons, while it is currently in the list of children.

```
 greatestparent   person  child      level
 ID123            ID123    ID345      1
 ID123            ID123    ID346      1
 ID123            ID345    ID456      2
```

So, I end up with the above data, but I want:

```
 greatestparent   person  child      level
 ID123             ID123    ID345      1
 ID123             ID123    ID346      1
 ID123             ID345    ID456      2
 ID123             ID346    n.a.       2
 ID123             ID456    n.a.       3
```

Needless to say, the data is vast, so it is not possible to just check by hand when the family dies out. Families also die out at different rates, so it is not always the last year. For speed I currently run the entire process for all families at the same time. Doing so for each family separately is not feasible.

The question: how do I get the 'last child' of a line to be named as a person as well. So, when a line dies out before the maximum line is reached, copy child to new observation of person.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't persist in using the `melt` method, the following code might be useful for you.

### Code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create the sample dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame({'greatestparent': {0: 'ID123', 1: 'ID123'}, 'person': {0: 'ID123', 1: 'ID123'}, 'child': {0: 'ID345', 1: 'ID346'}})
dfmerge = pd.DataFrame({'person': {0: 'ID123', 1: 'ID123', 2: 'ID345', 3: 'ID346', 4: 'ID456'}, 'child': {0: 'ID345', 1: 'ID346', 2: 'ID456', 3: np.NaN, 4: np.NaN}})

# Define an output dataframe
df_out = pd.DataFrame()

# Merge until all the values in both person and child columns are null
i = 0
_df = df.rename(columns={'person': i, 'child': i+1})
while _df.loc[:, i:i+1].notnull().any(axis=None):
    # Append a dataframe of i+1 generation
    _df_out = _df.assign(level=i+1).rename(columns={i: 'person', i+1: 'child'})
    df_out = df_out.append(_df_out, ignore_index=True)

    # Get data of the next generation
    i += 1
    _df = _df.merge(dfmerge.rename(columns={'person': i, 'child': i+1}), how='left', on=i)
    _df = _df.loc[_df[i].notnull(), ['greatestparent', i, i+1]]

print(df_out)
```

### Output:

| greatestparent | person | child | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID123 | ID123 | ID345 | 1 |
| ID123 | ID123 | ID346 | 1 |
| ID123 | ID345 | ID456 | 2 |
| ID123 | ID346 | nan | 2 |
| ID123 | ID456 | nan | 3 |

Comment: Note: I took `n.a.` in your sample dataframe as `np.NaN` not string. If `n.a.` is actually string, tell me please and I will modify my code.